# How to play through a video by scrolling down a page

Tags: javascript, css, video, web, scroll

I wanted to make a website so that the visitor can scroll down the webpage to crush my head against the top of the screen as the video gets pushed up.  How do I play through a video by scrolling down a page?  How would I correlate the scrolling of the site to the playing position of the video?

Comment: ..."crush my head against the top"?  ..what?

Comment: I imagine he has a picture of someone (himself) on the page. When the user scrolls down, naturally the picture will hit the edge on the top of the screen. He wants to correlate that with a little animation showing him suffering.